# new to ruby, help with simple output

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn ruby, and i am trying to do the exercise on this site and need help
[learn ruby](http://ruby.activeventure.com/tutorial/part_02/user_input.html)

Write a program that asks for a number and a sentence and prints the sentence backwards that many times. It should:

[image]

```
puts "Enter A Number?"
repeatHello = gets
i = 0
begin
   puts "hello world!" + i
end while i > repeatHello
```

Comment: What is your question?  There is sample code on the site you link to (the stuff in the gray Emacs windows).  Try it.  Post what you've tried.  Let us know in what way it isn't working, or if you have questions about it.  You question is too open-ended as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two mistakes in the code you pasted.  The first is that you need to add 1 to i each time it loops.  At the moment i is not increasing in value.

Within the loop (between begin and end) you need to increment i like so:

```
i += 1
```

(This shorthand for i = i + 1).

The second mistake is on the last line.  Currently it reads 'do this while i is greater than repeatHello', but i starts at 0, so its not going to be greater.

You need to switch it around to

```
while i < repeatHello.
```

You should end up with some code like this:

```
puts "Enter A Number?"
number = gets
puts "Enter A Sentence?"
sentence = gets

i = 0
begin
  puts sentence.reverse
  i += 1
end while i < number
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a clue (rather than doing it for ya ;) ). Grab the users input, and using the example of turning input into a number (`number  = gets.chomp.to_i`) use a loop (ex. `4.times do`) to output the reversed text that many times. You should be able to use this along with the help from that tutorial page to get this desired result.

EDIT WITH EXAMPLE (possibly more ruby-ish?)

```
puts "Enter A Number?"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter A Sentence?"
sentence = gets.chomp

number.times do
  puts sentence.reverse
end
```

Comment: is what i did up there printing hello world as many times as the user inputs?

Comment: Delameko's answer sums up the problem with your code as pasted, but a 'begin/end while' loop, while working, isn't necessarily the most...ruby way of doing things ;) check my answer edit for another example

Answer (score 1):

A very useful thing to learn about Ruby is that it almost never makes sense to just reproduce the structure you would have written in another language. In this case, for example, not only do you not need to manage your own counter in a loop, but you don't need to loop at all!

```
puts "Enter a number"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter a sentence"
sentence = gets
puts (sentence*number).reverse
```

Comment: @glenn-mcdonald that's a pretty cool little piece of syntactic sugar